# Tomcat 7.0.42 Error listenerStart

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

Am deploying my war file on tomcat(jdk 7) and am seeing following error. Am not sure of whats causing the issue.

```
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013)
Feb 27, 2014 11:02:50 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8081"]
Feb 27, 2014 11:02:50 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Feb 27, 2014 11:02:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1588 ms
Feb 27, 2014 11:02:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 27, 2014 11:02:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Feb 27, 2014 11:02:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive D:\Dev\tools\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapp
s\CollaborationPortal.war
Feb 27, 2014 11:03:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Feb 27, 2014 11:03:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Feb 27, 2014 11:03:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Feb 27, 2014 11:03:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/CollaborationPortal] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 27, 2014 11:03:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8081"]
Feb 27, 2014 11:03:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Feb 27, 2014 11:03:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 18890 ms
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can reconfigure [java.utils.logging](http://mythinkpond.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/tomcat-6-infamous-severe-error-listenerstart-message-how-to-debug-this-error/) by adding `/WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties` to your war archive:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

The actual error message should then be visible. Also, check your application logs, if an additional logging framework is already configured (eg. log4j).

Comment: Found the issue. My JAVA_HOME pointing to jdk 6 and I compiled my project in eclipse with JDK 7 and i was manually deploying on tomcat since my eclipse wtp publishing not working.  Tomcat using jdk 6 libraries but my application was not compatible with java 6. Changed JAVA_HOME to jdk 7 and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a mismatch in the JDK version you have installed and the JDK with which you are trying to build your project.

**1)**  If you are using **Eclipse**.Go to `Windows->Preferences->Compiler->check` the compiler compliance level (It should match with your installed JDK)

**2)**

- Right click on `build.xml`
- `Select Run As->Ant Build...` note the **ellipsis**!
- Switch to JRE tab
- Select the jdk from the list
- Build your project

  ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/26375026/5566348 )