# Error when deploying web application on Tomcat using Jenkins

Tags: tomcat

When I am deploying a web application on Tomcat by using Jenkins, I am facing a problem related to context path.

> Caused by:
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException:
>   The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context
>   path [/myapp] but context failed to start"

instead of the expected "OK" message.

Comment: Have you checked the log for any exceptions coming from the application itself? You may need to enable this [explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22076475/1535738) for that matter.

Comment: there is no any error in application, because when i run this application in IDE then it is working fine.